# jQuery Validation for unique numeric field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How do I validate a field, in my code below I want persal_no to only accept numeric values and be unique, as persal_no is a unique number given by the government to teachers. How can this be achieved using query?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#employeeDetailsForm").validate({
    rules: {
        "persal_no":{ required: true, maxlength: true}, 
        title_id: "required",
        emp_first_name: "required",
        emp_surname: "required",
        gender_id: "required",
        "email_addr": { email: true , required:true
    },
        id_no: "required",
        emp_tel_no: "required",
        emp_cell_no: "required",
        UserId: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        "persal_no": { required: "Please enter employee persal number", maxlength:"Maximum length 10 digits" },
        title_id: "Please select a title from the list",
        emp_first_name: "Please enter employee first name",
        emp_surname: "Please enter employee last name",
        gender_id: "Please select employee gender type",
        "email_addr": { required: "Please enter email address" , email: "Format incorrect" },
        id_no: "Please enter employee ID number",
        emp_tel_no: "Please enter employee telephone number",
        emp_cell_no: "Please enter employee cellphone number",
        UserId: "Please select a User ID"
    }
});

$("#create").click(function () {

    if (!$("#employeeDetailsForm").valid()) {
        return false;
    }

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        width: 540,
        height: 150,
        modal: true,
        hide: "clip",
        show: "slide",
        buttons: {
            "Confirm": function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/EmployeeDetails/Insert",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        persal_no: $("#persal_no").val(),
                        title_id: $("#title_id").val(),
                        emp_first_name: $("#emp_first_name").val(),
                        emp_middle_name: $("#emp_middle_name").val(),
                        emp_surname: $("#emp_surname").val(),
                        gender_id: $("#gender_id").val(),
                        email_addr: $("#email_addr").val(),
                        id_no: $("#id_no").val(),
                        emp_tel_no: $("#emp_tel_no").val(),
                        emp_cell_no: $("#emp_cell_no").val(),
                        UserId: $("#UserId").val(),
                        __RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        //var value = data.message;
                        //alert(value);
                        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                        $("#dialogSuccess").dialog({
                            resizable: false,
                            width: 540,
                            height: 150,
                            modal: true,
                            show: "slide",
                            buttons: {
                                "OK": function () {
                                    $("#dialogSuccess").dialog("close");
                                    window.location = "/EmployeeDetails/Search";
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                    }
                });
                //document.categoryForm.submit();
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: can you explain more about unique number

Comment: How could your JavaScript know if the number is unique?  You would have to keep track of all numbers somehow, like a database, and query it remotely.

Comment: Sure seems like you just dumped code here that has little to do with what you need, and expect us to figure everything else out for you.

Comment: I am using Jquery pop up notifications, therefore the validation that I had in my model had to be commented out in order for the notifications to function, I now have to use jquery to validate my add employee page, and I don't know how to validate a field to be unique or know if it can be done, I managed to figure out getting the fields to accept numeric text only ' "persal_no":{ required: true, maxlength: 10, digits: true, number: true}, '